# ES6 invoke class method by string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I(m trying to use a generic method to parse dom element and attach event Listener to them.

So I add an html5 data attribute to specify the method that should be call when we trigger the event.

What I'm looking for is a way to call the method inside the class by her string value :

```
static addEvent(element, trigger, action)
{
    element.on(trigger, action);
}
```

where element is the dom element where to attach eventListener, trigger is the type of listener and action is the method that we should call inside this class (here I want to call `toggleFullscreen`).

Is there a way to do that?

Edit : need to avoid `eval` solution, and I made a test with this[action] but it's not the excepted result.

Here is my code

dom element :

```
<div class="interface">
    <span class="home_common-fullscreen action fa fa-desktop" data-action="toggleFullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

javascript function :

```
class Interface {
    constructor() {
        this.domElements = jQuery(".interface");

        this.attachAction();
    }

    attachAction()
    {
        let fullScreenButtonElement = this.domElements.find(".action");
        if(fullScreenButtonElement !== undefined)
        {
            if(Array.isArray(fullScreenButtonElement))
            {
                jQuery(fullScreenButtonElement).each(function()
                {
                    Interface.parseAction(this);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Interface.parseAction(fullScreenButtonElement);
            }
        }
    }

    static parseAction(element)
    {
        let action = element.attr("data-action");
        if(action === undefined)
        {
            throw new InterfaceError("Trying to parse action element without defined data-action attribut");
        }

        let trigger = typeof element.attr("data-trigger") !== 'undefined' ? element.attr("data-trigger") : "click";

        try
        {
            Interface.addEvent(element, trigger, action);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(action + "not found in Interface")
        }
    }

    static addEvent(element, trigger, action)
    {
        element.on(trigger, action);
    }

    toggleFullscreen()
    {
        alert("foo");
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lerzats/ah8cr1ca/)

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `Interface`? Where did you try using the bracket notation? It should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Interface {
    // This method is a property of the class itself
    static addEvent(element,trigger,action) {
        element.on(trigger,Interface[action]);
    }

    // May need to be static if you don't plan on creating objects
    static toggleFullscreen() {
        console.log("It Works");
    }
}

// Or the Event Handler could be in another object
class EventHandlers {

    // It'd be accessed with EventHandlers["toggleFullscreen"];
    static toggleFullscreen() {

    }
}

// Or make it a global function
// Which would be accessed with window["toggleFullscreen"];
function toggleFullscreen() {

}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `static` if you don't plan on creating objects. You rather should not use `class` at all!

Comment: I wouldn't assume that using a class is inherently a problem, although I do think most developers would prefer to use a closure/module pattern in this case.

Comment: But this comment it's the point of the solution. As here, on this example it can be useless to use a class, but in the real code, this class do a little more than just use 3 static method.
And by saying that he point me to the fact that maybe I need to reconcidere using addEvent as static method rather than use it on Interface instancied object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

```
class XClass {
  f2() {
    console.log("Message from f2");
  }

  f4() {
    eval("this.f2()");
  }
}
```

But I think static will not work for this approach.

Comment: I would like to avoid eval, if it's possible

Comment: I think it is better to use just condition because of some security issue. Suppose you achieved what you need, then it will be possible to invoke "any" method by changing value of "data" attribute. So if (data=="blabla") attach(blabla) will be better option I think.

Comment: You're right, it would be my last resort if i can handle like i want. But here I show an example with dom value, but final purpose it's to attach the function name as callback in json recieved from server.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that, there is a way to access a method or property with just a string.

Comment: Yes, i know that in javascript < ES6, but with class i don't see how I can call like i used to do.

Comment: You can treat a constructed object or the class itself like an associative array

Comment: You point me on the right direction, I have already read post with this solution, but can't find the one with Class example. Still searching at this time.

Comment: I'll create one for you